# WordPress ajax function in child class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

If i have this classes

```
class something {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_func', array( $this, 'ajax_func' ) );
    }

    public function ajax_func() {

    }  

}
class stchild extends something {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function ajax_func() {
        echo "Test child1";
    }  
}
```

How to call only `ajax_func` function in `stchild` class by ajax ?
when i try this code

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'admin-ajax.php',
data: {action : 'ajax_func'},
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

it get all functions which called `ajax_func`, I want to define specific class to get this function from it.
Note that there is many child classes from `something` class and all are activated.

Comment: Isn't this a question for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ??  Er... wait a moment... why isn't this just a generic jQuery Ajax html question using JS objects instead of PHP?

Comment: OOps. I see it now, ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29  and  http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap it inside an action function.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_do_something', 'my_do_something_callback' );

function my_do_something_callback() {
    $object = new stchild;
    $object->ajax_func();
    die();
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl, // Use this pre-defined variable,
                  // instead of explicitly passing 'admin-ajax.php',
    data: { action : 'do_something' },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or you can just move the hook to the child class constructor.

Comment: @Mehul-Kaklotar all child classes have this function in ajax.